# What does the @model keyword do in an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some doubts about how to work a **@model** statement into a **cshtml** view. In my code, I have something like this:

```
@model MyCorp.EarlyWarnings.WebInterface.Models.HomePageModel
```

So what exactly does this do?

I think that I am including this **HomePageModel** as a model for the current view, so an object that is an instance of this class contains all the information that I have to show in this view. Is this interpretation correct or am I missing something?

Another doubt is: who populate this model? is it populated by the specific controller of the view?

Comment: Please stop prepending each of your questions with _"I am pretty new in [...]"_. That is no excuse for not doing research. Please start by reading through the [ASP.NET MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) to get a grasp of the basic concepts, especially the "Strongly Typed Models and the @model Keyword" section in [Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller).

Comment: Related: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 5):

The thing you have to remember is that the Razor View engine compiles your CSHTML pages into normal C# classes.

So when you define

```
@model Something
```

Razor actually produces something along the lines of

```
public class _Path_To_View_cshtml : WebViewPage<Something>
{
    // mcguffins to make everything happen
}
```

Then within that class everything is "inverted" from your CSHTML page. So when you write

```
<div>@Model.Foo</div>
```

in your CSHTML, this will be translated to something like

```
WriteLiteral("<div>");
Write(Model.Foo);
WriteLiteral("</div>");
```

---

In terms of the second part of your question about where Views are called from, any Controller Action can call a View (in the same application at least) by supplying the path to the view in the result:

```
return this.View("~/path/to/view", someModel);
```

The default is that if you return

```
return this.View(someModel);
```

the path used will be `~Views/ControllerName/ActionName.cshtml`

Answer (score 4):

> I think that I am including this HomePageModel as model for the current view so an object that is instance of this class contains all the information that I have to show in this view, is it interpretation correct or am I missing something?

Yes, you have interpreted it correctly.

> is it populated by the specific controller of the view?

Yes, it is populated by a specific action of the specific controller for that view.

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET MVC, a controller can pass strongly-typed models to its view. This can be done with the following kind of code in your controller method:

```
public ActionResult Show()
{
    MyModelClass model = new MyModelClass()

    return View(model);
}
```

Then, in order to access your strongly-typed model in your view, you need to first define (in your view) the type of model it is expecting. This is done by including a `@model` directive at the top of your view file:

```
@model Full.Namespace.MyModelClass
```

This allows the view to then access your models property in a strongly-typed manner, by using your model properties:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyProperty)
```